# Track connections and packets into socket (linux networking)?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel

What is the best way to tell if traffic is reaching a socket? 
netstat -i is convenient for checking counters in/out of an interface, but how to tell if that traffic is reaching a socket?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use netstat to check the count of ESTABLISHED connection to the port number that the socket is using to listen. Alternatively tcpdump can show you packets flowing in and out of that port.